# How to see matches of search in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I have a search line where a user enters query divided by commas. I need to find at least 1 matches in the SQL-table. But I need to mark the matches in each found object too. How can I do this?

Working search (Laravel Eloquent (PostgreSQL) without marking matches):

```
public function searchOfAuthor(Request $request)
{
    $search = array_map('trim', explode(',', $request->get('search')));

    $columns = [
        'city',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'skype',
        'icq',
        'vk'
    ];

    $authors = AuthorMask::where(function ($query) use ($columns, $search) {
            foreach ($search as $searchKey) {
                if (!empty($searchKey)) {
                    $query->orWhere('name', 'ILIKE', '%'.$searchKey.'%');
                    foreach ($columns as $column) {
                        $query->orWhere($column, 'ILIKE', $searchKey);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        ->with('author')
        ->orderByRaw('company_id = ? desc', Auth::user()->company_id)
        ->paginate(5);

    if (empty($authors->items())) {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => null,
            'error' => 'Authors Have Not Been Found'
        ], 404);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => [
            'authors' => $authors
        ],
        'error' => null
    ], 200);
}
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Hey, if your looking into advance search capability, you should probably have a look at Laravel Scout: http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout

Comment: @JulienBourdeau Hi! I tried Scout but it's not work for me (used with Algolia Driver). Installed by instruction, search queries are displayed on Algolia site, but return is empty. Idk why.

Comment: If you're willing to give it another try, let me know, I can help you with that. You can post on discourse.algolia.com (I'm monitoring Laravel question) or here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing condition like `ILIKE` in laravel or Mysql. There should be `LIKE`. There are two lines of codes have `ILIKE`.

`$query->orWhere('name', 'ILIKE', '%'.$searchKey.'%');`

`$query->orWhere($column, 'ILIKE', $searchKey);`

Remove `I` from `ILIKE` of above two lines. After removing `I` from `ILIKE` it should look like

`$query->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchKey.'%');`

`$query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', $searchKey);`

Comment: I use PostgreSQL. It has ILIKE (ignorcase LIKE).

Answer (score 0):

Did it. Just created new array for mark of matches. Another question: who know how to append array to the object in pagination?

```
    $matches = [];
    foreach ($authors->items() as $author) {
        $matches[$author->id]['name'] = 0;
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $matches[$author->id][$column] = 0;
        }

        foreach ($search as $searchKey) {
            if (!empty($searchKey)) {
                foreach ($author->toArray() as $key => $attribute) {
                    if (!strcasecmp($searchKey, $attribute)) {
                        $matches[$author->id][$key] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => [
            'authors' => $authors,
            'matches' => $matches
        ],
        'error' => null
    ], 200);
```